# Finding immigration and surname record russia to Leeds uk

Tags: immigration, united-kingdom, russia, ukraine

My great grandfather Jacob Masson came to Leeds in c.1900 from Odessa area i think in Russia, now Ukraine.

I would like to find out his original surname and any passenger and immigration records.

Also any information on the family in Russia before Jacob Masson came to uk.

He married Fanny Masson (maiden name Hochenberg). I have found census records when they were living in the Uk.

Answer (score 2):

The UK never kept passenger lists for passengers arriving from Continental Europe - see [The National Archives Guide on Immigration and Immigrants](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/help-with-your-research/research-guides/immigration). There may be other records relating to naturalisation (if he did) or other aspects - that Guide mentions some and links to other Guides that might (maybe, possibly!) help.